# gui help... with an actionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, jtextfield

I'm writing my first GUI program that actually does something and I am having problems with the action listener. The program when complete will take a double input and make conversions from one unit to another based on some radio button selections which i haven't added yet. The problem right now is the Action listener doesn't recognize my text fields.

I have an input text field and an output text fields in separate panels. I created an action listener and I added the input text field to the listener.

ActionListener handler = new HandlerClass();
        textField.addActionListener(handler);
then I created an in class definition for the handler class but when I write the action preformed method textField and output cannot be resolved by the program. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class conversionDisplay extends JFrame{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel northPanel;
private JPanel southPanel;
private JPanel eastPanel;
private JPanel westPanel;

public conversionDisplay() {
    super("Temperature Conversion");


    northPanel = new JPanel();                          //create northPanel
    northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
    northPanel.add(new JPanel());
    JPanel northLabelPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) ;
    northLabelPanel.add(new JLabel("Input"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    northPanel.add(northLabelPanel);
    JTextField textField =new JTextField(10);
    northPanel.add(textField);
    northPanel.add(new JPanel());


    southPanel = new JPanel();                          //create southPanel
    southPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    southPanel.add(new JPanel());
    JPanel southLabelPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    southLabelPanel.add(new JLabel("Output "), BorderLayout.EAST);
    southPanel.add(southLabelPanel);
    JTextField output;
    southPanel.add(output = new JTextField( 10));
    output.setEditable(false);
    southPanel.add(new JPanel());





    add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);                 //add north panel
    add(southPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);                 //add north panel


    ActionListener handler = new HandlerClass();
    textField.addActionListener(handler);

    setSize(350, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setVisible(true);
}
private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double input = textField.getText();
    if (input != 0)
    {

        output.setText(input);  //Perform conversion
    }

}



}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textField JTextField is declared inside of a constructor and is thus only visible within that block (again the constructor). You need to make it an instance field of the class.

i.e.,

```
public class Foo {

  private Bar bar = new Bar();  // this field is visible throughout the object

  public Foo() {
    Baz baz = new Baz(); // this is only visible within this constructor
  }
```

So just like the bar variable above is visible while the baz variable that is declared in the constructor is not, you'll want to move your JTextField variable declarations *out* of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

you must parse   String to Double value

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double input = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
    if (input != 0)
    {
        output.setText(input+"");  //Perform conversion
    }

}
```

and declare `JTextField output,textField` as Globel.

Comment: That's wonderful advise, but the question is "how" does the OP reference the textfields ;)

Comment: i cant get you. how means??

Comment: The basic question is, the OP is having difficultly resolving the references to the textfields that they want to access...If you try and compile the OPs code, it won't, because `textField` and `output` are unknown variables...

Comment: Not that you advise is wrong, it's just not addressing the core problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class conversionDisplay extends JFrame{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JPanel northPanel;
private JPanel southPanel;
private JPanel eastPanel;
private JPanel westPanel;
JTextField output = new JTextField(10);    

public conversionDisplay() {
    super("Temperature Conversion");
```